# Advanced Installer is not working

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project, advanced-installer

I have a problem, I am trying to build an msi setup for windows C# based application. Its a windows desktop application. When I build the setup using the Visual studio 2010, its successful its working but whenever I use [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) its giving me an error. It jumps to middle of the application and generates an error. Here is what I am doing:

I have configured the first part, means the application information clearly using the tutorial. Here is a link to the tutorial:
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html
In application folder, I added the whole release folder,[ I have built my application in the release folder]
I have made a shortcut too for the executable file.

It builds successfully but when I run it, its giving me error after the installation?

The reason I am using Advanced Installer is that I need some customized prerequisites and also check the registry for certain values. And I think Advanced Installer gives these options. Any other options would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the error. The error was when I was making shortcut to the executable on desktop folder in the Advance Installer, I was renaming it to some name, taking the .exe extention truncated all the time. But it was weird that it was running but not working. I kept the name with the proper extension. Now its working :) –Make sure that you don't remove the extension .exe of the shortcut you make either in the desktop folder or any other folder you access.

Answer (score 2):

So the error appears after the installation? i.e. when you launch your installed application using the shortcut, yes? If so, it seems that you are missing some dependencies for your assembly. Have you tried the option "Add dependencies" for your main executable? Just go to Files view, right click on it and you will find it in the context menu.

Comment: I basically added the dependencies. I figured out the error. The error was when I was making shortcut to the executable on desktop in the Advance Installer, I was renaming it to some name, taking the .exe extention truncated all the time. But it was weird that it was running but not working. I kept the name with the proper extension. Now its working :)